# How to use fold without making the list mutable?

Tags: rust

I have provided an example here:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Example {
    name: String,
    description: String,
}

fn main() {
    let lines = vec![
        "N: N1",
        "D: D1",
        "",
        "N: N2",
        "D: D2",
        "",
    ];

    let data = lines.into_iter().fold(Vec::<Example>::new(), |acc, line| {
        let mut examples = acc;
        match line.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>().as_slice() {
            ['N', ..] => {
                let mut element:Example = Default::default();
                element.name = line[2..].into();
                examples.push(element);
            }
            ['D', ..] => {
                let mut element = examples.pop().unwrap();
                element.description = line[2..].into();
                examples.push(element);
            }
            &[_, ..] => {}
            &[] => {}
        }
        return examples;
    });

    for example in data{
        println!("Name: {}, Description: {}", example.name, example.description);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2c3268d18c9617286e8fb338b78c3c59)

Basically, I will be processing a steam of lines (the amount unknown at runtime, I have used an array here for the purpose of the example) and I want to build up a struct with the information and when I reach a given termination point, I start a new struct and add it to the list.

My first attempts at this used an outer most mutable list.  I then discovered the fold method which seemed more elegant (IMO) but I still have to make the list mutable inside.

What would be a better way of achieving this and/or how could I remove the need to make the list mutable?

Comment: Please include the code in the question, not as a link. Don't fret about using `mut` inside of the fold - it only applies to inside the closure.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have this same structure (only 2 fields, 3 rows per record), and you can have 2 independent iterators over the data,
it is possible to do a trick:

```
    let names = lines.iter();
    let descriptions = lines.iter().skip(1);
    let name_desc_pairs = names.zip(descriptions).step_by(3);
    let examples = name_desc_pairs.map(parse_example);
```

Where `fn parse_example(lines: (&String, &String)) -> Example` would take a pair of `(name_line, description_line)` strings and construct an Example.

Otherwise if you want arbitrary number of fields, consider that while you iterate over lines, at first you only get a partial example, so some buffering of the partial state is needed. There are no methods for that in the standard Iterator.

There's [chunks](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.17/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.chunks) method in the `futures` crate if you can use that: `stream::iter(lines).chunks(3)` spits out vectors of 3 lines, each of which you can parse into an Example.

Without that it's possible to [implement your own buffering & parsing Iterator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/index.html#implementing-iterator).
The idea is that the iterator state contains a partial example, e.g.:

```
struct ExampleBuilder {
    name: Option<String>,
    description: Option<String>,
}
```

and wraps the original iterator. In its next() method it calls next() of the original iterator a few times, and either adds line data to ExampleBuilder, or when it gets `""` separator - converts ExampleBuilder to Example and returns it.